# how to set text in edit box which is retrieved from database(by using php file)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I am using `.php` file to retrieve data from database using 1 unique field (mobile number in my case) and paste it in my `xml` file,
for example my **database** contains fields **name, mobile, message**.. and even my `xml` contains **name, mobile, message editboxes**. So the data present in database should be the `.setText()` of my editboxes.

here is my code::

```
EditText name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);                   
string nm = json_data.getString("name"); //data at name is assigned to nm successfully 
name1.setText(nm.toString()); //this line is not doing the task giving an exception(fatal exception asynctask #1)
```

Please suggest me what should I use instead of setText to assign the value to my editbox. I tried `ExtractedSetText` and `string.getText.tostring`, searched to resolve "fatal exception asynctask #1 " but didn't helped.

Any suggestions would be of great help
Thanks

in postExecute(line:163)::

```
Details.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
         EditText name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
         Log.e("onPostExecute nm", nm.toString());                     
         name1.append(nm.toString());
         //but its throwing a null pointer exception
         //name1.setText(nm.toString());  //this is not doing the task
    }
}
```

log cat::

```
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at com.example.pinks.Details$Fetch$1.run(Details.java:168)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4766)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at com.example.pinks.Details$Fetch.onPostExecute(Details.java:163)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at com.example.pinks.Details$Fetch.onPostExecute(Details.java:1)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
12-25 14:36:50.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17901):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is this code executed in doInBackground of the async task ? could you please paste the code .

Comment: exactly..it is in doInBackground,extended async,this part is in for loop..only this line is giving the error

Comment: actually doInBackground is executed on a background thread and you can only change the UI from the UI thread .its better to send the result to onPostExecute (running on ui thread) and change your UI their.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: did you tried this name1.setText(nm);

Comment: yes..even it is giving null pointer exception @ Darkie

Comment: you dont need to use Details.this.runOnUiThread in postExecute because its already executed on the UI thread .

Comment: i didn't get you..if we have to use Details.this.runOnUiThread then where we should do it..in doInBackground i have n number of try and catch blocks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,got a solution for this,thank you for helping me to find where i was doing mistake

Changes I've done::
In doInBackground

```
             nm=json_data.getString("name");
```

In postExecute

```
            EditText name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            name1.setText(nm.toString());
```

successfully assigned the text retrieved from database to .xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to change the UI in doInBackground()

```
   YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         name1.setText(nm.toString());
   }
  });
```

Or you can change the UI directly in postExecute()

hope this will help :)

Comment: its giving null pointer exception..
                 Details.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                 {
public void run() {
EditText name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
  name1.append(nm.toString());//instead of setText i've used append..here it is giving the null pointer exception
            //name1.setText(nm.toString());--i've tried this statement too..but it's not working..
      }

Comment: could u paste the log cat please.and make sure that name1 is not null ?

Comment: if you want to change the UI from do in background use Details.this.runOnUiThread (...)
otherwise (in post execute ) you can set the text directly name1.setText(nm);

Comment: in postExecute i've declared edit text-name1 and assigned the value of nm to name1 using "name1.setText(nm);" still it is throwing null pointer exception..but when i print the value of nm in log am able to retrieve it..it is displaying the name "prathibha"

Comment: it seems that name1 is null because if you call name1.setText(null); it won't raise exception make sure that name1 is not null ...
try name1.setText("some text"); in the post execute

Comment: name1 is the editbox where i have to set the text..it will be null before asigning any value..

Comment: EditText name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
should return the edit box view object and then you assign the text to that edit text (name1).

Comment: we are doing the same here i guess..why it will take null value.it is going out of my mind